# htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I use right now:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule !^index.html http://samedomain.com [L,R=301]
```

so that all inquires go the http://samedomain.com ...(usualy it would load index.html)
the index.html is excluded so it does not come a endless loop.

i can open http://samedomain.com/index.html  FINE.. it does not come redirected.
And other requests to subpages come redirected to http://samedomain.com
BUT it does not open the page.

Would be great you can tell me how to redirect all requests to
http://samedomain.com AND how to exclude 2 Files (the index.html and an image.jpg)
excluded from that rerouting.

thx
chris

Comment: This is a Server Fault question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?image\.jpg$
RewriteRule /?(.*) http://samedomain.com/$1 [L]
```